# Class object in App class - set details on multiple pages

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Mobile App Development and have only basic experience with C#. I would like to create an object in App.xaml.cs so that I can use this object in multiple Xamarin.Forms pages. This is the code in the App.xaml.cs that is placed before public App():

```
public BookingDetails bookingInfo;
```

BookingDetails class:

```
 public class BookingDetails
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Hostel { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to set some of the details in a Xamarin.Forms page:

```
 App.bookingInfo.Hostel = hostel_name;
 App.bookingInfo.CheckIn = DatePickerFrom.Date;
 App.bookingInfo.CheckOut = DatePickerTo.Date;
 App.bookingInfo.Price = total_due;
```

Currently, this results in the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'App.bookingInfo'

I have tried to include static, but this still results in null. How can I solve this? Thank you.

```
public static BookingDetails bookingInfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize the instance before you can use it

```
if (bookingInfo == null) bookingInfo = new BookingDetails();
```